# Exclude bad ram bytes

Tags: ram

I have 5 bytes (or bits, don't know) of bad Ram. How can I exclude these bytes so my Ubuntu 11.10 don't use them. My PC randomly freez, and when I ran memtest it reported 5 errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that I know of is [BadMem](http://badmem.sourceforge.net/) (by Rick van Rein), who is able to block bad memory sectors in Linux.

It works by instructing the kernel to lock those memory addresses you specified. This effectively stops Linux from ever addressing those addresses when allocating (and deallocating) memory.

You can read all about at  [the BadMEM-HOWTO page](http://badmem.sourceforge.net/docu/BadMEM-HOWTO.html)!

---

**Possible auxiliary documentation can be found at:**

[BadRAM - Community Ubuntu Documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM)

[Linux Journal - Running Linux with Broken Memory By Rick van Rein](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4489)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this was possible.

Comment: @RobinJ, found it some time ago, when dealing with this problem on an old computer, where memory modules are very pricey :)

Comment: How to install it. Documentation is not complete

Comment: @Alen, you can check [BadRAM - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM) for more instructions.

Comment: I excluded bad adresses using instructions on link that @Zuul provided. and I will report you tomorrow if it is successuful

Comment: this is what I get:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/p3067632.jpg

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/p3067631.jpg

can you tell me how to exclude this in GRUB. I tried using BADRAM option in memtest but no luck

Comment: @Alen, have you read the links that I've posted? You need to patch the kernel with BadRAM, it has nothing to do with GRUB or memtest! You seem to have misunderstood the BadRAM usage.