# bad ram in DIMM1 need to limp by till monday, can I temporarily disable a memory slot?

Tags: freeze, ram

Got to work, started windows, immediately blue screened as soon as I logged in. After a few tries I ran diagnostics and found the ram in dimm1 was bad.

I can boot into Ubuntu and it runs pretty well I can at least get some work done this way but I do get frequent lock-ups which I suspect are ram related.

Is there anyway to temporarily just disable that memory? I have 16 gig so I would have plenty left without that chip.

I cannot physically remove it as the laptop (dell xps 9530) requires a t-2 driver to open and I don’t have one here. Also the buses home don’t start till 3pm and its only 11am so I am stuck for now.

Ideas?

Comment: Run down to the hardware store and buy a t-2 driver?

Comment: :) yeah I thought about that. its quite a hike to get to office depot from here. I haven’t ruled it out yet though.

Comment: There is something called the BadMEM project that aims at not using bad memory units. See [here](http://badmem.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: yeah I looked into that but didn't understand it at all. I am new to Linux. I guess I was hoping there might be some magic "turn off dimm1" check box :)

Comment: Your best bet would be booting with the memmap= parameter. See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-kernel-parameters.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently (I don't want to test this) GRUB2 has an option allowing the masking of bad memory cells, on a byte-by-byte basis.  You will need to use the memtest boot options to determine the bad adresses, and list them in the grub configuration file as

`GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"`

using your addresses, of course.  The links I found referencing this are

[Exclude bad ram bytes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151843/exclude-bad-ram-bytes)

https://blog.hartwork.org/?p=1712

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM#BADRAM_setting_in_Grub2

http://foundations-bugs.gmang.org/2014-April/187827.html