# Can I disable one slot of RAM?

Tags: ram

My laptop has onboard 4 GB DDR4 RAM and one normal. The onboard RAM is faulty and causes a lot of problems.

My question is, can I disable the onboard RAM and make my system use only the other one?

Comment: Why don't you physically remove it?

Comment: @FedKad - I think he’s suggesting one module is soldered on, the other is ‘normal’ removable ddr4 ram.

Comment: There isn't anyway to disable RAM as far as I know, but there is a way to have Ubuntu ignore the bad RAM, but you need to know the addresses of the RAM in question.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/908925/how-do-i-tell-ubuntu-not-to-use-certain-memory-addresses

Comment: sadfully the physical removing of ram module unavailable right now because there isn't any schematic for theis motherboard 
about GRUB_BADRAM its not working because all of the 4gb is bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell ubuntu not to use certain memory addresses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908925/how-do-i-tell-ubuntu-not-to-use-certain-memory-addresses)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bad ram in DIMM1 need to limp by till monday, can I temporarily disable a memory slot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488922/bad-ram-in-dimm1-need-to-limp-by-till-monday-can-i-temporarily-disable-a-memory)

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't disable the onboard RAM.

You usually can't disable it, unless there is an option on BIOS, but i never saw something like that.